Which L-functions are not known to be automorphic for $\mathrm{GL}_n$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\sym{sym}$I would like to compile a list of primitive L-functions which satisfy
the usual axioms (Dirichlet series with an Euler product,
and a functional equation of a standard form, conjectured to
satisfy a Riemann hypothesis), but which are not known to
come from a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\GL_n$.
(That is, they conjecturally are the standard L-function of a cuspidal automorphic
representation of $\GL_n$, but that has not yet been proven.)
For example, if $f$ is a cusp form on $\Gamma_0(N)$ (holomorphic
or Maass), then by work of Kim and Shahidi $L(s,f,\sym^9)$
is on the list.  But by work of Kim, $L(s,f,\sym^4)$ is not.
Prior to the work of Arthur, the spin L-function of a Siegel
modular form on $\operatorname{Sp}_4$ or the paramodular group $K(N)$ was on the
list.  But the proof of the conjectured lift to $\GL_4$ removed
it from the list.

Any sort of Rankin-Selberg integral for $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_m$ with $n,m \geq 2$ and $\max{n,m} \geq 4$.

Recent work of Newton and Thorne gives automorphic of symmetric power L-functions for holomorphic (Hilbert) modular forms.

Just for clarity, for people who might not realize what's going on, presumably the question implicitly means the standard $L$-function attached to a cuspform on $GL_n$, as opposed to other $L$-functions attached to other repns of the $L$-group... in line with Langlands' conjectures.

Yes, the standard L-function.  Question updated.

@DavidFarmer When $f$ is a $\mathrm{GL}_2$ cusp form, not of solvable polyhedral type, then $L(s,f,\mathrm{Sym}^9)$ is only known to be holomorphic for Re(s) ≥ 1 (Kim-Shahidi IMRN 2006), but the meromorphic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$ is known (Kim-Shahidi Duke 2002).  So I don't think this example satisfies your criteria yet.

@PeterHumphries The OP requires primitivity, and the current literature only ensures primitivity in your examples when $n,m\leq 3$ and $n m\leq 6$ (and then, the $L$-functions are known to be products of standard $L$-functions). For example, given two holomorphic newforms $f\neq g$ on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the primitivity of $L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^2 f\times \mathrm{Sym}^2 g)$ is not known despite its good analytic properties. However, if $\mathrm{Sym}^2 f\times \mathrm{Sym}^2 g$ is automorphic, then it follows from Kim's work on $\mathrm{Sym}^4$ that it is cuspidal (implying primitivity).
